# Implement stack using a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement Stack using a linked list. Looking for code-review, best practices and optimizations.

```
public class StackUsingLinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> top;
    int size;

    public StackUsingLinkedList() {
    }

    private static class Node<T> {
        Node<T> next; 
        T item;

        public Node (T item, Node<T> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Push the item into the stack
     * 
     * @param item  the item to be pushed.
     */
    public void push(T item) {
        final Node<T> node = new Node<T>(item, top);
        top = node;
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Pops the item from the stack 
     * 
     * @return  the popped item
     * @throws EmptyStackException if attempt is made to access/pop out of an empty stack.
     */
    public T pop() { 
        if (top == null) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }

        T item = top.item;
        top = top.next;
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item at top of the stack.
     * 
     * @return  the item at top of stack.
     * @throws EmptyStackException if attempt is made to access empty stack 
     */
    public T peek () {
        if (top == null) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        return top.item;
    }


    public int size() {
        return size;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackUsingLinkedList<Integer> s = new StackUsingLinkedList<Integer>();
        s.push(10);
        s.push(20);

        // expected 20, 10.
        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(s.pop());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is generally good code, with standards-conforming names and style.

It appears that `size` is an afterthought variable. It is not scoped as being 'private', and it is not decreased in the `pop()` method, so it is buggy in two ways.

Additionally, even in the inner private Node class, I would recommend declaring the `item` and `next` as private, and also adding getters/setters for them.

Otherwise, this is good code.

Comment: Thanks - just in my opinion adding private modifier and getter/setters for inner classes may be an overkill.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper - that's fair. I see it both ways, and it is just a preference. The private is not completely redundant. Oh, the constructor you have is redundant. Still, this code (with the fixed size bug), would pass a review of mine.

Comment: All fields should be private and/or final, or I would search all the assignments to it to see what's unusual in the way it is used (friend access etc.). (re getters/setters on inner class: Assigning private fields of the inner classes from the enclosing class is also bad style, as it misleads the reader; although it is not the case here.) In this case `item`, `next` could be `final`.